# alt+f2 in XFCE4 makes me loose my selection

Tags: xfce

Does anyone have a solution to prevent <kbd>alt+f2</kbd> from stealing the selection in Linux Mint Xfce4?

E.x.: I have a URL to paste into the URL bar (say I used <kbd>ctrl+c</kbd>), then I open `brave-browser` with <kbd>alt+f2</kbd>, then `xfrun4` triggered by <kbd>alt+f2</kbd>, and when I do paste <kbd>ctrl+v</kbd>, instead of my URL I have by example `ve-browser`.

Maybe something in `gsettings` or I need to fill a bug report?

```
lsb_release -cir
Distributor ID: Linuxmint
Release:    21.1
Codename:   vera
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I use `parcellite` clipboard, and I had ticked 'synchonize clipboards' in preferences, now solved.